# Create a Google doc and direct a url to it?

Tags: microsoft-word, adobe-reader, documents

How can I copy a pdf to a Google doc and then direct a url to that doc?

Comment: Super User is intended for computer hardware and software related questions only.  Web services such as Google Docs are considered off-topic.  Please see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

Get the share link of the google doc. Then provide that link as the embedded link. If you want to code your HTML use the anchor tag.